# row substraction in lambda pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lambda, apply

I have a dataframe with multiple columns. One of the column is the cumulative revenue column. If the year is not ended then the revenue will be constant for the rest of the period because the coming daily revenue is 0.

The dataframe looks like this

[image]

Now I want to create a new column where the row is substracted by the last row and if the result is 0 then print 0 for that row in the new column. If not zero then use the row value. The new dataframe should look like this:

[image]

My idea was to do this with the apply lambda method. So this is the thinking:

{df['2017new'] = df['2017'].apply(lambda x: 0 if row - lastrow == 0 else x)}

But i do not know how to write the row - lastrow part of the code. How to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can shift the data and fill the values based on condition using `np.where` i.e

```
df['new'] = np.where(df['2017']-df['2017'].shift(1)==0,0,df['2017'])
```

or with `df.where` i.e

```
df['new'] = df['2017'].where(df['2017']-df['2017'].shift(1)!=0,0)
```

```
   2016  2017  new
0    10    21   21
1    15    34   34
2    70    40   40
3    90    53   53
4    93    53    0
5    99    53    0
```

Answer (score 3):

By using `np.where`

```
df2['New']=np.where(df2['2017'].diff().eq(0),0,df2['2017'])
df2
Out[190]: 
   2016  2017  New
0    10    21   21
1    15    34   34
2    70    40   40
3    90    53   53
4    93    53    0
5    99    53    0
```